# jquery Google type suggest with restrict to list

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autosuggest

I currently have functionality on a page to give a user suggestions based on what they type in a text box (jquery suggest). The functionality I would like to add is to restrict what gets selected / entered into the text box to only be items in the list.  Basically like a combobox which restricts its selections to what's in the list.

One thought I had is to verify that the entry in the textbox matches to an item in the list.  I would have to alert the user that what is entered isn't allowed (or maybe there is a way to keep them typing other characters?), it's OK, but not real clean ui.

I figure someone on SO has done something like this; if someone has an idea to achieve this functionality please let me know.

---

The basic jquery I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete("getPcodes.aspx", { mustMatch: true, autoFill:true, multipleSeparator: "; ", minChars:3 });
    });
</script>
```

There are a lot of nice options with the autocomplete.  I was using a suggest jquery before, but I think I will opt for this one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) lets you force the user to select an option from the returned dataset.

Check option mustMatch in http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions:

> If set to true, the autocompleter will only allow results that are presented by the backend. Note that illegal values result in an empty input box.

Comment: Just as an update the mustMatch option is a nightmare and doesn't work so well.  Haven't discovered why I am having the issues, but I surely am, plus a whole lot of others too on the jquery forum

Comment: 3 years later: the autocomplete plugin has been integrated with jQuery UI, and many of the options (including mustMatch) have been dropped.