# how to restrict user to select form ajax auto compleate suggestion

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i am using following code for ajax suggestion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    setAutoComplete("searchField", "results", "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/autofillvalue/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>?part=");
});
```

and in html my code is

```
<div class="input text required" id="auto">
      <input id="searchField" type="text" name="searchField" class='inp-form' autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

the suggested code is json encoded. i want to restrict to end user only to select form suggested value. how it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are obviously aware, the [JQuery documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) details an option called `mustMatch`. But as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728596/jquery-google-type-suggest-with-restrict-to-list), it's not usable. However, to the rescue comes [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete/7113981#7113981). in which there are several suggestions as to how to get round the problem. Here is one solution from that page, written by @Anonymous and @Elliot:

Add this:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
         $(this).val('');
     }
}
```

and this:

```
autoFocus: true
```